# What's the purpose of _dl_sysinfo_int80?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I mean, why not to issue the `int` instruction directly?

```
Dump of assembler code for function execve:
   [omitted]
   0x0806c282 <+18>:    call   *0x80e99f0
   [omitted]
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disas *0x80e99f0
Dump of assembler code for function _dl_sysinfo_int80:
   0x0806ed70 <+0>: int    $0x80
   0x0806ed72 <+2>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

From my inexperienced point of view, `_dl_sysinfo_int80` adds nothing but overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways to perform a system call. The oldest and slowest is the `int 0x80`. The advantage is that it works on all systems. Later, intel introduced the `sysenter` and amd introduced the `syscall` instruction. These are unfortunately not compatible, and only work on certain chips. So that the best implementation can be used, a level of indirection has been added. The kernel itself normally provides entry code mapped into every process (part of the vDSO). As far as I can tell, the `_dl_sysinfo_int80` is just used as a fallback when that kernel provided code is for some reason not available.